# Firebase, user registration and navigation issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I'm using React Native, Firebase and react-navigator.

In the LoadingScreen Component I observe the state changes (onAuthStateChanged)

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = setInterval(
            () => firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                user ? this.props.navigation.navigate("App") : this.props.navigation.navigate("Auth");
            }),
            30,
        );
    }
```

In my AuthStack in the ChooseRole Component I have a function in which I want to register a user along with the role to be performed.

```
if (this.state.role === 'child') {
                Firebase
                    .auth ()
                    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword (email, password)
                    .then (() => {
                        const addChildRole = fc.httpsCallable (('addChildRole'));
                        addChildRole ({email: this.state.email}). then ((result) =>
                            this.setState ({role: result}));
                    })
                    .catch (errorMessage => {
                        console.log (errorMessage)
                    });
            })
```

The problem is that before .then() calls in witch I add a role, the Auth state probably changes and navigates to the application. In the AppStack, the Direction Component, based on the role, I want to target the child or parent component, but by calling

```
firebase.auth (). CurrentUser.getIdTokenResult ()
         .then ((idTokenResult) => {
         if (idTokenResult.claims.parent || idTokenResult.claims.child) {
}
```

idTokenResult.claims.parent and idTokenResult.claims.child gives undefined.

I want to handle giving users the role of registering and logging in, then moving to the appropriate component using Direction.js.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

*Not necessarily the cause of your problem, but too long to put in a comment.*

There is no need to repeatedly call `onAuthStateChanged`. You can call it just once, and it will listen to auth state changes from that moment on. Calling it in short intervals as you're doing it bound to give problems.

Do this in `componentDidMount` instead:

```
componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        user ? this.props.navigation.navigate("App") : this.props.navigation.navigate("Auth");
    });
}
```

---

What could well be the cause of the problem is indeed that the `onAuthStateChanged` is fired before your database write completes. You can easily verify this by adding some logging statements.

If it is, you have two main options to fix the problem:

1. Don't use an `onAuthStateChanged` listener in `componentDidMount`, but simply check the value of `firebase.auth().currentUser`. This does not use a listener, so does not interfere with the database write.
2. Remove the `onAuthStateChanged` just before creating the user, so that it doesn't fire. You can do this by keeping the return value from the call to `onAuthStateChanged`, which is an unsubscribe function. So something along the lines of:

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
       stopAuthStateListener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
           ...
   ```

   And then:

   ```
   if (this.state.role === 'child') {
       stopAuthStateListener();
       Firebase
           .auth ()
           .createUserWithEmailAndPassword (email, password)
           ...
   ```